# No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_behavior' in package

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, tabs

My application worked fine until I tried to add a library to it. After I added the library, Android Studio gives me the following error:

> Error:(26) No resource identifier found for attribute
>   'layout_behavior'  in package 'inf..'

This is my build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:utils-v4:1.3.0@aar'
    compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.3.0@aar'
    compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.1.0'
    // compile 'com.lorentzos.swipecards:library:1.0.9@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
    compile project(':swipelib')
}
```

This is the xml which causes the error:

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

I tried the following:

- Removed the library
- Reset Android Studio and my computer
- Reverted to previous version of my code from git.

However, the error persists. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

That string resource is defined within the Material Design support library.

Since you're not using the `CoordinatorLayout` from the Material Design support library, you should be able to safely remove the `app:layout_behavior` attribute.  It was probably cut & paste from other code.

NOTE: If you are actually using `CoordinatorLayout` and want the cooperative scrolling behaviors to work, you need to add the dependency for the latest version of the Material Design Support library to your Gradle build file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

---

UPDATE: Note that with the latest versions of Gradle the `compile` configuration has been deprecated in favor of `implementation` and `api` configurations so your dependency could look like this:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
```

This is only an example; the version numbers may be out of date when you read this, so make sure your version matches the version of the support library that you want to use.

For more info: [What's the difference between implementation and compile in gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle)

Comment: Please be sure that you are using the latest version of the design library. In order to get the latest version check the official page of the design library. https://developer.android.com/training/material/design-library.html#AddDependency As of writing this comment the latest version is ```compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1' ```

Comment: In app/build.gradle I put version 26.1.0 within "dependencies{compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0}" _ it works thanks! @kris larson!

Answer (score 45):

Just in case someone else comes from Google and makes the same mistake I did, it's `layout_behaviOr`, not `layout_behavioUr`.

Answer (score 25):

For those who use AndroidX and don't want to add the old library:

```
com.android.support:design:28.0.0
```

you can add instead:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

and use it like this:

```
app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
```

Comment: In addition, `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` also works after adding the material library.

Answer (score 18):

**Note**: The versions have changed by now, so replace below versions with the most recent ones.

The accepted answer gets rid of the error in case layout_behavior is not needed, however if you actually want to use:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Make sure to add the proper dependency to the build.gradle file of your module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

   //Other stuff....
}

dependencies {

    //Importing the design library fixes the build
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'

    //Other libraries....
}
```

I.e. add this line to your dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```

Comment: but how on earth would you know that `com.android.support:design:23.1.0` is the solution to a broken  `app:layout_behavior   = "@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd I just tried it out, as I was having the same problem at some point

Comment: my library already has this dependency still it shows same error. When I add design library to app project gradle dependency then it goes away. Why  do i have to add it to app project when it's already there in library? any solution?

Comment: @Asu Not sure what's going on there, but also beware that the versions have changed by bow - so you should use the most recent design library version. You could check if you find some information regarding the behavior you mentioned here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html

Answer (score 7):

if you not added android material yet first add this line in your dependencies in build.gradle file

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

then use this attribute instead

```
app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
```

Comment: Even i was getting this error in "compileSdkVersion 29". So, I have added this line implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'. It resolved the error.

Answer (score 6):

for those using androidX

```
com.android.support:design is now moved to com.google.android.material
```

you will need to include this

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02'
```

Comment: `com.android.support:design is now moved to com.google.android.material`

Answer (score 5):

Replace "**app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior**" with **app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior**"

Answer (score 4):

I am using Androidx,so i implemented `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha05'`

but its still giving me error `Unresolved class @string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior`

so i found just Invalidate caches / Restart

Quickest way to do that is File → Invalidate caches / Restart... → Just Restart.

I hope its help you.

**Note:** In Android Studio v3.4 showing `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` Unresolved class `@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` but work when you run your app.

Comment: thx, Just Restart make it work in v3.4 , but several minutes later, it auto turned red

Comment: I have migrated to androidx packages (i.e. implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'), and am seeing this same thing. I invalidated caches and restarted, red error went away for just a few seconds, then came back.

Comment: @tfrysinger run your app its work and the red error always exists until next update :)

Comment: It only occurs in new Android Studio 3.4. Following the issue here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131403371

Comment: @kdblue you are correct. In Android Studio v3.4 , showing app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" Unresolved class @string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior but work when you run your app.

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem. and i resolved my problem with tow steps.
1- Download last version of AndroidSupportLibrary package and AndroidSupportRepository package(or upgarad them to the newest version) in SDKTools of android sdk manager .
2- Change support depenedencies ind build.gradle fiel to

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.+'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add compile `com.android.support:design:23.0.1`
into your `build.gradle` dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

[AgentKnopf Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34066985/7817893)
"Make sure to add the proper dependency to the build.gradle file of your module", then I would add, you also make sure the module is same as your current version like this: compile 'com.android.support:design:**25.3.1.0**
if you are not using compile 'com.android.support:design**:23.1.0**'