# [Android][App]Error:(5) No resource identifier found for attribute 'shortcutId' in package 'android'

Tags: java, android, sdk, shortcut

Good morning guys,
i'm trying to add launcher shortcuts(introduced by google with the release of android 7.1.1 - API 25) to my android application but i'm getting those errors. Can somebody give me an help to solve this?
Thanks in advance

Errors:

```
C:\Users\stackoverflow\Desktop\myapp\app\src\main\res\xml\shortcuts.xml

Error:(5) No resource identifier found for attribute 'shortcutId' in package 'android'
Error:(5) No resource identifier found for attribute 'shortcutShortLabel' in package 'android'
Error:(5) No resource identifier found for attribute 'shortcutLongLabel' in package 'android'
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32832717/no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-layout-behavior-in-package) SO question.

Comment: @JeroenHeier thank you dude!