# Bdsk sample Make error

Tags: android, bluetooth

I got some errors while trying to Make sample Bdsk file. As a novice to Android Studio I would appreciate very much to let me know how to fix these errors.

I use the sample source code according to this instruction:
To use the solution code, create a new Android Studio project using the name "Bdsk" and Company domain "bluetooth.com". When the project has been created, replace the contents of the folder Bdsk\app\src\main with the contents of the Bluetooth Developer Starter Kit folder "Android\Source\solution" (except for thie readme file).

[image: Bdsk sample Make error]

Answer (score 0):

> No resource identifier found for attribute

Those errors are not with Bdsk. You are not compiling the Android Support Design Library.

Check your Gradle file for a dependency  `android.support.design`. If there isn't a line with that, there's the problem

[No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_behavior' in package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32832717/no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-layout-behavior-in-package)

You'll want to update the version number accordingly