# Bdsk sample error

Tags: android, bluetooth

As a beginner working through the Bluetooth Developer Starter Kit https://blog.bluetooth.com/bluetooth-developer-starter-kit-v3-2
I got stuck on page 24 of "Bluetooth Developer Starter Kit - Hands-on Lab (Android) V3.2.pdf" - "*Use the Android Studio auto-completion facility (select item in error and press Alt+Enter) to generate stub implementations of the three methods defined by this interface.*" I have no idea what this means or what to do so then I downloaded the complete Bdsk files as suggested into Android studio 2.3 and attempted to make the project but got the warning:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources]
C:\Users\james\Documents\AndriodProjects\JimsAndroids\Bdsk\app\src\main\res\layout\content_main.xml
Error:(2) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_behavior' in package 'com.bluetooth.bdsk'
Error:(11, 26) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_behavior' with value '@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior').
C:\Users\james\Documents\AndriodProjects\JimsAndroids\Bdsk\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\layout\content_main.xml
Error:(2) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_behavior' in package 'com.bluetooth.bdsk'
Error:(11, 26) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_behavior' with value '@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 0.744 secs
Information:5 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: Please post the documentation you are referencing.

Comment: Please see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42751055/bdsk-sample-make-error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout\_behavior' in package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32832717/no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-layout-behavior-in-package)