# Exception : No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_behavior' with value '@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior')

Tags: android, android-layout, android-library, android-coordinatorlayout

I am developing a library. I am developing it by making a new library module in an application project where it works fine(even if I remove design library from app gradle file.). But when I tried to use it in different application by taking the .aar file from "library -> build -> outputs -> aar" folder and adding it as new java/.aar module it doesn't build and shows below exception :

```
Error:(36, 30) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_behavior' with value '@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior').
```

The exception is in all the layout files of library. Almost all the related Stackoverflow posts tell this error occurs if you have not included "com.android.support:design" in gradle. But my library gradle file has this library. Below is a layout file from library with error :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/lib/lib-package-here"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
```

I changed the third line from "/apk/res-auto" to current one after reading few SO posts.
What's happening here? What are the things I should do for seamless integration of my library in other apps?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32832717/no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-layout-behavior-in-package

Comment: I am using support coordinatorLayout and I have included design library as said in this post

Comment: I'm having the same issue