# Android Studio layout_behavior error

Tags: android, xml, android-bluetooth

Any advice why I'm getting this error on layout_behavior, and how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that you have a different label than this: `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`

maybe you have `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout`.

If so, you should change it to **android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout**, since the child elements can apply the attribute `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

Answer (score 1):

For Androidx I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55763152/2828651) and got problem solved.

summary:
In Gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha05'
```

in XML:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

If not solved then Invalidate caches / Restart

Answer (score 0):

`layout_behavior` attribute is part of the `CoordinatorLayout`. It defines interaction behavior plugin for child views of CoordinatorLayout.

In your case you can either delete this attribute (`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`) from your code or wrap your `RelativeLayout` with`CoordinatorLayout` if you need behavior functionality.