# RecyclerView Rendering Issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I want to implement recycler view layout, but I am getting error "render problem". I tried to add *include*, but the error still exists. How can I solve the problem ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/viewBg"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.waadalkatheri.popularmovies.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
    <include layout="@layout/activity_main"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

image the error 
[image]

the error:
I

```
nformation:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources]
/Users/mac/AndroidStudioProjects/popularMovies/app/src/main/res/layout/content_main.xml
Error:(2) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_behavior' in package 'com.example.waadalkatheri.popularmovies'
Error:(8, 26) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_behavior' with value '@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior').
/Users/mac/AndroidStudioProjects/popularMovies/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/layout/content_main.xml
Error:(2) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_behavior' in package 'com.example.waadalkatheri.popularmovies'
Error:(8, 26) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_behavior' with value '@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

Comment: Can you show that error?

Comment: can you share the error??

Comment: i'm share the error @sumit

Comment: have you added the recycler view dependency in your build.gradle file??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

Just remove `tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"` from your RelativeLayout

*You can find the solution of render problem below the render error warning!!!*

Answer (score 1):

Remove this  `android:scrollbars="vertical"` form your code and try rebuilding the project

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, since you are not using *CoordinatorLayout*, you can safely remove the problematic `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`. Read more about it here: [No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_behavior' in package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32832717/no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-layout-behavior-in-package)

Then, I think your **android:showIn** xml attribute is superfluous. Get rid of it. You are recursively referring to the same activity (with **include** and **showIn)** and that's what messes up your rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Search all your project with keyword: "layout_behavior" and remove all lines of them. Especially, in "content_main.xml"

Answer (score 0):

ok I think I found your problem.

Just change this one line in your xml:

```
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"  to tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main.xml"
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Well, you don't really need to add .xml after specifying the @layout/something path. Android Studio will deduce the rest itself :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your app's build.gradle

```
dependencies{

         compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

         compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:your_version'


       }
```