# can´t add the android:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilcolapsed">

Tags: android, android-studio

I nerd to create sticky headers in my android application. So I followed a tutorial to create them and in it the user has added to lines in his xml file.

This are the lines:

```
android:layout_behavir="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
android:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilcolapsed">
```

But when I try to add the two lines to my code the autocomplete don't recognize them and if I add them anyway the application gives an error.

I have read around and what I found was to include the android.support.design library. I have don that but my problem persist.

Can someone give mi a full example of how to put this to work?

This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.manuelrodrigues.myapplication.ScrollingActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilcolapsed"
                android:layout_behavir="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilcolapsed">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:background="#ff0000"
                    android:text="Teste" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:background="#00ff00"
                    android:text="Teste3" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this are my imported libs:
[image: And this are my imported libs:]

Comment: there is a typo mistake at **android:layout_behavir** which should be **android:layout_behaviour**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **`app:layout_scrollFlags`** instead of **`android:layout_scrollFlags`** .

1. Wrong tag name  **<s>android:layout_behavir</s>**

**Don't**

```
android:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilcolapsed"
android:layout_behavir="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

**Do**

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilcolapsed"
android:layout_behaviour ="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

You should include below in **Parent Layout Section** .

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Finally **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`** .

Comment: I have tried to change from android: to app: but it doesn't recognize the app:. It says "Namespace 'app' is not bound"

Comment: Is it something with the library?

Comment: @Manuel_Rodrigues did you add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` in root tag section

Comment: I have added the line xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" but it says the same that the app: is not recognized

Comment: @Manuel_Rodrigues I have edited my answer . Have a look

Comment: I'm havinga an other problem now in the android:layout_behaviour. It  says: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_behaviour' in package 'android'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32832717/no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-layout-behavior-in-package

Answer (score 0):

**change this..**

```
android:layout_behavir="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
android:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilcolapsed">
```

**to**

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilcolapsed"
android:layout_behaviour ="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Comment: I have tried that already but it doesn't recognize the app:. It says "Namespace 'app' is not bound"

Comment: add this name space     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its `exitUntilCollapsed` and not `exitUntilcolapsed`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.manuelrodrigues.myapplication.ScrollingActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                android:layout_behavir="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:background="#ff0000"
                    android:text="Teste" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:background="#00ff00"
                    android:text="Teste3" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```