# Can anyone explain me about "app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Can anyone explain me about this property `"app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32832717/no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-layout-behavior-in-package , look for kris larson's answer

Answer (score 2):

Change  `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout ✖`
to **android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout ✓**
then the child elements can use `app:layout_behavior`

Answer (score 1):

If you use `CoordinatorLayout` you can use layout behaviors such as hiding `FloatingActionButton` while scrolling list or hide toolbar while scrolling list. The behaviour you are asking about is used for the 2nd case, where this behaviour should be set on view which triggers toolbar scrolling. This string resource contains class name which defines the behaviour. You can create custom behaviours as well.